# Trying to insert input type date into mysql column of type date throws SQL error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have two fields in my form named `from date` and `to date`, both have input type date. I am inserting these two fields in my DB with column type date.

My html looks like:

```
<form class="" action='a.php' method="POST">
<label for="From_date" class="left-text">From Date:</label>

<input type="date" name="from_date" maxlength=""   id="fromdate" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
<label for="To_date" class="left-text">To Date:</label>

<input type="date" name="to_date" maxlength=""   id="todate" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
```

My php looks like this:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'ads');

$link = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
  OR die("could not connect");

$from_date= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['from_date']);
$from_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from_date));

$to_date= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['to_date']);
$to_date= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($to_date));
```

In my insert statement I am doing this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO airport_data (From_date,To_date) VALUES ('$from_date','$to_date')";
```

But this throws me this error:

> Could not able to execute INSERT INTO table (From_date,To_date) VALUES (2015-05-27,2015-05-15). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From_date,To_date) VALUES ( 2015-05-27,2015-05-15) at line 1

I tried to change the date format from the form:

```
$to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $to_date)));
$from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $from_date)));
```

But this didn't solved the problem neither.

Where is the problem, that I can't insert the dates received from my form into my database table?

Comment: `(From_date,To_date,)` <= see that *trailing* comma? Get rid of it. Edit: Oh, it's a typo. Nice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- mistakenly typed its not there actually

Comment: um... I'm wondering; what MySQL API are you using to connect with?

Comment: Try to print out `$sql` variable and see what you get.

Comment: @Fred-ii- iam using mysqli

Comment: where exactly is this in your code? `$to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $to_date)));
    $from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $from_date)));` and the sequence.

Comment: it is actually replacing - between y d m with /

Comment: @Fred-ii- here is the error ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO table (From_date,To_date) VALUES (2015-05-27,2015-05-15). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From_date,To_date) VALUES ( 2015-05-27,2015-05-15) at line 1

Comment: post your full code including your HTML form.

Comment: the error you're showing us, doesn't support what you posted for code. sorry. `for the right syntax to use near 'From_date,To_date)` that tells me you've a syntax error here.

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan 1. Please make sure your show us your **full** and **real** code (Including connection; Including html form) 2. Add error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and tell us if you get any! 3. Make sure your MYSQL table name , column names matches and the type is really DATE. 4. Also check for errors when you are connection 5. If you get any errors make sure you show us the **full** and **exact** message which you get

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO airport_data (From_date,To_date) VALUES ('".$from_date."','".$to_date."')"; change to that

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan That's not everything. Read all my points above ^. Also 1. How do you submit your form? 2. What do you input into the fields ?

Comment: @Rizier123 is submit by submit button i input dates in them throught html5 input type date

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan Did u try changing ('".$from_date."','".$to_date."') ?

Comment: @ledesma yes did still got error "ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO airport_data (From_date, To_date) VALUES ('2015/05/27','2015/05/13') . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From_date, To_date) VALUES ('2015/05/27','2015/05/13')' at line 2 "

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan You have to change the format first: $from_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$_POST['from_date'])));

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
$from_date = new DateTime($_POST['from_date']);
$to_date = new DateTime($_POST['to_date']);

// Insert the following into the database
$from_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $from_date->format('Y-m-d'));
$to_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $to_date->format('Y-m-d'));

// If you want those slashes
$from_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $from_date->format('Y/m/d'));
$to_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $to_date->format('Y/m/d'));
```

And for your query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO airport_data
(From_date, To_date)
VALUES ('".$from_date."','".$to_date."')
";
```

A simple yet elegant way to output dates the way you want them to.

Comment: Why are u doing this echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); P.S How can i use mysqli_real_escape_string with ur answer

Comment: To be able to see the output. This is not necesarry of course.

Comment: This is fine for development, but use prepared statements in production.

Comment: thanks for the edit Peter, I accepted it but I may end up deleting my answer. The OP's question is unclear as to how/where their code is setup including the sequence. Edit: I deleted my answer. @Peter